# How can highlight a date in jQuery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, razor

I cannot dynamically highlight the date in calendar, only static dates highlight if I do:

```
eventDates[new Date('01/09/2018')] = new Date('01/09/2018')
```

Here is my code:

```
$(function() {
  // An array of dates
  var eventDates = [];
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "@Url.Action("
    GetEvents ", "
    Home ")",
    dataType: "json",
    data: "",
    success: function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(i, val) {
        var dd = CTD(val.Date); //CTD means convert into date 
        eventDates[i] = dd;
      });
    }
  });
  // convert in date
  function CTD(d) {
    var date = new Date(parseInt(d.substr(6)));
    var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    return date.getDate() + "/" + month + "/" + date.getFullYear();
  }

  //eventDates[new Date('01/09/2018')] = new Date('01/09/2018');

  // datepicker
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      var highlight = eventDates[date];
      if (highlight) {
        return [true, "event", 'Tooltip text'];
      } else {
        return [true, '', ''];
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: What language are you using, C# or VB? And what language are using for your views, Razor or ASPX?

Comment: asp.net mvc Razor (C#) use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then in the `DatePicker`, you are searching in the array indexes, so you will not find the date. To find the date you need to use the `indexOf()` method and you need to format the `DatePicker` date in the same format that you saved in the array:

```
var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
date = date.getDate() + "/" + month + "/" + date.getFullYear();
var highlight = eventDates.indexOf(date);
```

Instead of repeating the code to format the date, you extract the formatting code from your `CTD()` function into a new function:

```
// convert in date
function CTD(d) {
  var date = new Date(parseInt(d.substr(6)));
  return FD(date);
}
// format date
function FD(d) {
  return d.getDate() + "/" + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + d.getFullYear();
}
```

And finally, you want to make sure that the code for the DatePicker will only run after the Ajax result comes back, so put in a function and call it from the `success` of the Ajax:

```
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "@Url.Action("GetEvents", "Home")",
    dataType: "json",
    data: "",
    success: function(data) {
      var eventDates = []; //An array of dates
      $.each(data, function(i, val) {
        eventDates[i] = CTD(val.Date); //CTD means convert into date 
      });
      HighlighEvents(eventDates);
    }
  });
  // convert in date
  function CTD(d) {
    var date = new Date(parseInt(d.substr(6)));
    return FD(date);
  }
  // format date
  function FD(d) {
    return d.getDate() + "/" + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + d.getFullYear();
  }
  // datepicker
  function HighlighEvents(eventDates) {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
      beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var highlight = eventDates.indexOf(FD(date));
        if (highlight > -1) {
          return [true, "event", 'Tooltip text'];
        } else {
          return [true, '', ''];
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: it is not use full and i am not using any input filed

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment. You said your date is coming from the database. That would be in the controller, so how are you sending it from the controller to the view? I gave an example if you use the model. If you use the `DataView` instead, the code will be similar. Post your code in the question if you need help.

Comment: data send in json form from controller               like                                                                      
                                                                                                            
    public JsonResult GetEvents()
        {
            var events = db.Events.ToList();
            return new JsonResult { Data = events, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
        }

Comment: Oops!, I forgot to change your original condition `if (highlight)`. It should be `if (highlight > -1)`. See my updated answer.

Comment: and update enventDates[i] for multiple Highlight instead of eventDates[1]

Comment: plz some more help please tell me how to add anchor tag of highlight date on calendar???

Comment: You have to create a new question and post all the relevant information.

Comment: This is my new Question link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48538733/how-to-apply-anchor-tag-on-highlight-dates-in-calendar-using-jquery-ui if you know please reply me..